# PostgreSQL - divide query result into quintiles

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a PostgreSQL SQL SELECT results. I need to divide rows into quintiles and update quintil value to the specific row.

Is there some possibility to do this requirement in SELECT without need to do it in application? I would like to avoid situation when I need to select data to application and do the ranking out of PostgreSQL server.

Data example - first column is value, second column is quintil

```
4859 - 5
4569 - 5
4125 - 4
3986 - 4
3852 - 3
3562 - 3
3452 - 2
3269 - 2
3168 - 1
3058 - 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a window function called "ntile" to produce this: you give it a parameter specifying how many "tiles" the output it covers should be divided into (5 in this case).

For example:

```
select t.id, ntile(5) over (order by t.id)
from t
```

See [window function tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for an introduction to window functions, and [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) for a list of the standard ones supplied.

Comment: How did we ever get anything done without window functions? I'm finding myself using them rather frequently, where I might've in the past used client-side processing, convoluted hacky SQL, PL/PgSQL, etc. They just make things so much easier.

Comment: @CraigRinger: maybe we'll be saying the same about "lateral" after 9.3 comes out? (I know I've wished for it in the past)

Comment: Oh, we will. I've had to mangle several queries pretty horribly to use Pg's SRF-in-SELECT syntax via nested queries in cases where LATERAL would've done the job very nicely.